# $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p $ is non abelian of order $p^3$ with element of order $p^2$

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

I've encountered a text claiming that:

$$L:=\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_p $$ when the semidirect product is defined using:

$$\beta: \mathbb{Z}_p \to Aut(L)$$

$$ \beta ([1])=\alpha_{[p+1]}$$

where $\alpha_{[p+1]}(g) = g^{p+1}$

is a non-abelian group of order $p^3$ which has an element of order $p^2$.

I can only justify why it is non-abelian, and that is by using a theorem that states that a semidrect product is abelian iff each of its constituents is abelian and $\beta$ is trivial. Since $\beta$ here is not trivial, then this is not abelian.

I cannot seem to justify the rest -- why is it of order $p^3$? And how can I show there's an element of order $p^2$? (perhaps for the latter it would be sufficient to show that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is cyclic with generator $a$ and then take $(a,1)$? But I'm unable to prove that it's cyclic (and I actually think it cannot be because then it would 'collapse' to $\mathbb{Z}_p$) - **EDIT:** I can see this would be obtained using Cauchy from knowing it's $p^3$. So now I'm still left with that $p^3$).

What am I missing?

Comment: https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Order_of_semidirect_product_is_product_of_orders

Comment: @StevenStadnicki so where am I wrong with my reasoning that the order of $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2}$ is $p(p-1)$ (the number of elements invertible mod $p^2$)?

Comment: It seems like there are big gaps in your understanding. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is cyclic for any $n$ (including $p^2$), it is generated by $1$. What is the order of $(1,0)$ in your semidirect product?

Comment: In general, the semi-direct product $A\rtimes B$ includes a subgroup isomorphic to $A.$ Here $A$ has a element of order $p^2.$

Comment: $\mathbb Z_{p^2}$ is the additive group, not the multplicative group of the ring. $(\mathbb Z_{p^2},+).$ The multiplicative group is usually written $\mathbb Z_{p^2}^{\times}.$

Comment: Thank you both - I'm a bit rusty so I keep mixing up the additive group with the multiplicative group...

Comment: Which text are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remark that $G$ is the semidirect product of two subgroups $H, K$ iff the following holds :$H$ is normal, $$G=HK$$, $$H\cap K=\{e\} $$ In particular, the map
$$H\times K \to G$$
$$f(h, k) =hk$$ is a bijection.
So, $$\lvert G\rvert =\lvert H\rvert \times \lvert K\rvert =p^{3}$$
Moreover Cauchy give the existence of elements having prime order for every prime dividing the order of the group, so it doesn't give elements of order $p^{2}$,in fact your first choice can be modified, to consider the element $(a, 0)$ which has order $p^{2}$.